# comparing 2 columns in a data-frame and creating a new column in data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, apache-spark-sql

I have "merged" data from 2 data frames, & I have compared 2 columns 'answer' & 'selected_answer' I got the values true & false in column final_ans by doing below code,

dt$final_ans<- dt$correct_answer==dt$selected_answer

but I want to add another column 'score' based on the values of column `final_ans` if true then want to display 3 in column score like wise if false then display 0.
this below is the code what i have done but with wrong answer. It displays only 0 for all rows as shown below.. how do edit the code to get exact values.

```
    Q_id c1  c2 c3 c4 answer stu_id selected_answer  final_ans score
     2   1   2  3   4   2    82       3                false     0
     3   1   2  3   4   2    58       3                false     0
     3   1   2  3   4   2    83       2                true      0
     3   1   2  3   4   2    100      3
     4   1   2  3   4   1    79       3
     5   1   2  3   4   1    100      3
     7   1   2  3   4   1    54       3
     7   1   2  3   4   1    92       3
     8   1   2  3   4   3    56       2
```

Comment: Which other questions did you go through? What have you tried already?

Comment: I get that. What have you tried to do to solve your problem? This is an extremely basic R operation which should have thousands of tutorials / answers / tips across the internet.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=r%20compare%20columns%20in%20data%20frame the first link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying a logical vector by say 3, you replace `TRUE` with 3 and `FALSE` with 0. i.e,

```
rt$is_correct <- dt$correct_answer==dt$selected_answer
rt$is_correct * 3
```

If your column with `final_ans` is not logical, but rather a character, then you need to convert it first and then create your new column.

```
dt$final_ans <- as.logical(dt$final_ans) #to convert to logical
dt$score <- dt$final_ans * 3 #to create your new column
```

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: see updated answer. I think your `final_ans` is not in fact logical

Comment: I really don't know what the problem is.

Comment: You mean instead of 3 & 0?

Comment: No it will always give 0 for `FALSE`. You can however manually change the 0 values to -1 by numerous ways. For example: `dt$score[dt$score == 0] <- -1`

Comment: Well, `ifelse` is one way to go. i.e. `dt$score <- ifelse(dt$final_ans == 3,3,0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
dt <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=5:1) # here are your 2 'answer' columns
dt$test <- dt$a==dt$b # here is your test for correct answer
dt$score <- dt$test * 3 # here is the score you give for a 'TRUE' answer
dt
```

Comment: I see no reason it should not work. But I don't read your example very easily, so just give it a try ! The size of your data won't be of any trouble here. ;)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. Maybe you should try to edit your first post for your piece of code to be displayed more clearly. Remember : select your code and CTRL+K will enlighten it over a grey background.

Comment: change this `dt$final_ans<- dt$correct_answer==dt$selected_answer ` to `dt$final_ans<- dt$answer==dt$selected_answer `. But I am not sure i understand what you are doing. Sorry !

Comment: Because the logical elements (TRUE & FALSE) are automatically mapped to integers (1 & 0) when they are applied an algebraic operator (the * here). So 3*1=3 and 3*0 =0 !

Comment: No but you would just have to add `dt$score[dt$score == 0] <- -1` at the end of the previous example for it to work !